# Post Recipient View Without Their Credentials

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to receive the Recipient Url for embedded signing within our application.

I won't have the user's credentials, and all my API calls are going through as a Ds administrator account.

When I execute the following I get an error message:

```
{
  "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_ENVELOPE",
  "message": "This account is not authorized to access the requested envelope."
}
```

If I execute this against envelopes that are assigned to me it works fine but not other users. I should also point out we are not currently making use of clientUserId when creating recipients. Only a small portion will need embedded signing.

It was my understanding an administrative account would be able to retrieve the url needed to begin the embeded signing process. Is this not correct?

Also under what circumstances would email and userName not be the same? Aren't usernames always email addresses?

Request :

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/244043/envelopes/41d02a5f-13f8-4fb5-897d-142e1c653645/views/recipient
X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>blah</Username><Password>blah2</Password><IntegratorKey>blah3</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "returnUrl": "http://www.[somedomain].com",
 "email" : "someguy@gmail.com",
 "userName" : "someguy@gmail.com",
 "authenticationMethod" : "email"
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Additionally if I try the following for my request :

```
{
  "returnUrl": "http://www.[mydomain].com",
  "userId" : "xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
  "authenticationMethod" : "email"
}
```

I receive :

```
{
  errorCode: "INVALID_USERID"
  message: "Invalid UserId. UserId specified in request does not match authenticated user."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the issues in Luis Scott's answer, you're missing one of the required parameters for the [Recipient View](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Recipient%20View.htm) method --

> **clientUserId** A sender created value that shows [that] the recipient is embedded (captive). Maximum of 100 characters.

Create a value for the `clientUserId` and include it for the signer when you create the transaction (when you send the signing request).

Then include it when you want the Recipient View. It's a security measure to ensure that it is ok for your web app to authenticate the signer.

Only include the clientUserId for signers where you can authenticate them yourself and you plan to offer them the embedded signing view.

Comment: Thanks Larry, spot on.

Answer (score 1):

1) Please ensure the user being used for the API calls has the "Account-Wide Rights" setting enabled under preferences -> users -> permissions.

2) The Username field should be the recipients full name that was provided during envelope creation. So it would be "Some Guy" IMO using your sample above.

Comment: I have verified the Account Wide Rights for user making API calls and modified the json request as you suggested by i receive the same error message.